# When redirecting in bash to stdout or stderr, I actually get redirected to a file

Tags: bash, redirect, ssh, stdout, stderr

I'm saving the output of one command executed on a remote via ssh, but I also execute some echos. In order to see the messages on the screen and not save them to the variable I want to redirect them. 
I have tried >&1 and >&2 but in each case a file is created with the name either "1" or "2"
Is this an issue of expanding quotes or escaping characters?

```
OUTPUT=$(sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'echo "Message1" >&2 ;
                                          su -lc "./rootscript.sh" >&2; 
                                          echo "$?" ')
echo "su output is: $OUTPUT"
```

Output:

Nothing on screen, a file named "2" with the text "Password" inside (assuming Message 1 was overwritten) The program still waits for a password, even without a prompt, so when I enter it the output is good:

```
su output is: 0
```

How can I get my messages to show on screen?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `OUTPUT` to contain anything except the exit status; the output of `su` is redirected to standard error, so not captured by the command substitution. The fact that `>&2` seems to be interpreted as `>2` does stump me, though.

Comment: I strongly recommend using public-key authentication instead of `sshpass`, regardless.

Comment: Is the default shell for `user` on machine `ip` actually the C shell — or some other non-POSIX shell?

Comment: @chepner, I am not certain whether to call it exit status or output, but when the password is correct I get a 0, otherwise I get a non-zero. This value is stored correctly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the shell is bash... In my test the machine running the code connects to itself or another virtual machine running linux enterprise

Comment: What, if anything, happens differently if you use `sshpass -p password ssh user@ip bash -c '…'` (with the extra arguments `bash` and `-c`) in the command line?  In theory, it should make no odds if the original script is executed by `bash`.  OTOH, if it behaves differently, then there is a strong inference that the original script was not being executed by `bash`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, same result!

could it be that while in ssh the stdout is no longer referring to my LOCAL stdout? this "2" file is being created on the remote after all...

Comment: Same result is at least self-consistent; it is just a bit baffling too. Like @chepner, I'm trying to think of a way that `>&2` can be treated the same as `>2`.  Do you have IFS set to include `&`?  That's stretching things to the limits, but might account for it (though it is highly improbable that it is the trouble).  Where is the file `2` created? On the local machine or on `ip`?

Comment: @natharra, creating a file named `2` is what would happen if the `&` weren't there. Given that it is, I'm almost wondering if sshpass is failing to pass its arguments through unmodified.

Comment: @natharra, ...to answer the question you asked @JonathanLeffler -- `>&2` does indeed refer to the remote stderr rather than the local stderr when it's inside the single-quotes. However, since the remote stderr is piped back to the remote stderr by ssh, that doesn't explain the problem at all -- `>&2` is, even if remote stderr vs local stderr, still stderr (which is to say, file descriptor number 2), not a file named `2`.

Comment: @natharra what does `sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'ps -p $$; true'`  print?

Comment: @thatotherguy I removed my line of code completely, and replaced it with yours. Here is the output:

`PID    TTY        TIME CMD`
`32374    ?        00:00:00 tcsh`

Comment: That looks rather like a C shell derivative.  One more debugging option: replace the `bash -c '...'` with `bash -xvc '...'`.  The `-x` enables trace; the `-v` enables verbose mode, which prints the 'script' as it is read.  The `-x` output doesn't necessarily show the I/O redirection, but the `-v` output does show that.  But I suspect that despite your best efforts, it is a `tcsh` vs `bash` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonathanLeffler caught the problem right away -- you're not using bash, but tcsh.

tcsh has its own syntax incompatible with bash.

It doesn't matter though: since `ssh` and `sshpass` return the remote command's exit code, this is how you should be doing it:

```
if sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'echo "Message1"; su -lc "./rootscript.sh"'
then
  echo "The command succeeded (exit code $?)"
else
  echo "The command failed (exit code $?)"
fi
```

If you really wanted to run something in bash on the remote shell, you could do use Charles Duffy's code with a minor change:

```
                                      #    v-- shell specified here
output=$(sshpass -p password ssh user@ip bash << 'EOF'
   echo "Message1" >&2
   su -lc "./rootscript.sh" >&2 
   echo "$?"
EOF
)
```

Comment: Great workaround, no need for storing or re-directing, thanks! I will change my commands a bit, since I want the output of su that must be my LAST command performed in ssh, and I had an extra one, but its fixable :) !